# Variable not returning a boolean yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

I have been working on this code to return a Boolean value, what happens is that the variable gets overwritten with true or false as it looks for a row in the `foreach` statements. But when I pass it in my view file no value is taken/appears. Can you help me why this is happening and how do I successfully pass the boolean?

View file

```
echo TestController::Showprerequisites(29005);
```

Model

```
$validator;

foreach($prereq as $values){

 if(FinishedSubjects::find()->where(['subjectname' => $values['col']])->exists()){
   $validator = true;
 } else {
   $validator = false;
 }

}

return $validator;
```

Controller

```
  public function Showprerequisites($trno){
      $model = new TestModel();
      return $model->Showprerequisites($trno);
    }
```

EDIT
View update

```
$preq =  TestController::Showprerequisites(29005);

if($preq = true){
    echo 'Pre requites completed/read';
} else if($preq = false) {
    echo 'Pre requisites not completed/not read';
}
```

Comment: have you tried `echo false;` `echo true;`?

Comment: Probably it's not going in `foreach`?

Comment: if the value of $validator is false, you will not see anything on screen if you echo it but if true, echo $validator will show true on browser

Comment: how you pass to view ,display controller code

Comment: I have updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have logical error in your code, you are assigning value in if condition and then checking, it always return true.

Instead of this:

```
if($preq = true){
```

you can check this way too:

```
if($preq){ // if $preq is true then this line will work.
```